# Why does my mouse keep doing the loading sign?

Tags: mouse

I have been having a (hilarious) problem with my mouse pointer recently, in which it will not stop switching between the "working in background" pointer and the normal pointer. **Why is my computer doing this?**

For reference, this is happening on a Lenovo Thinkpad E480 with Windows 10 Pro. See this picture for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the busy icon on your mousepointer, the most obvous answer is: your computer is busy enough to trigger the busy icon.

If you are not doing anything and it still shows this, chances are really high that you either have one or more virusses or spyware infections on your computer. The busy icon is one of the symptoms of a serious infection.

It is possible there is a normal but heavy program running in the background eating resources and causing the busy indicator, such as torrent programs, but that often does not trigger a busy indicator.

Check your task manager to see what eats CPU and if there is no clear indicator, scan for viruses and malware.